# Different result with DSA (vertexArrayVertexBuffer, vertexArrayAttribBinding) than with glBufferData

Tags: opengl

I am trying to draw a triangle.  Here is my code:
    const char* vertexShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
        "layout (location = 0) in vec3 aPos;\n"
        "void main()\n"
        "{\n"
        "   gl_Position = vec4(aPos.x, aPos.y, aPos.z, 1.0);\n"
        "}\0";

```
const char* fragmentShaderSource = "#version 330 core\n"
    "out vec4 FragColor;\n"
    "void main()\n"
    "{\n"
    "   FragColor = vec4(1.0f, 0.5f, 0.2f, 1.0f);\n"
    "}\n\0";

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.0f,
    0.0f,  0.5f, 0.0f
};

// Create the VAO
GLuint vao;
GLuint buffer;

glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(float), (void*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

This results in the following image:
[image: triangle]

However, trying to use newer, DSA type methods does not draw the correct triangle.  If I switch my code to:

```
glCreateBuffers(1, &buffer);
glNamedBufferStorage(buffer, sizeof(vertices), vertices, 0);

glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, buffer, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 0, 0);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 0);
```

I get this image:

[image: squished triangle]

The triangle is squished.  In fact, changing any of the coordinates of the last row of vertices (the point that is squished) do not change the image result.  Why is this happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to call `glVertexArrayAttribFormat`:

```
glCreateBuffers(1, &buffer);
glNamedBufferStorage(buffer, sizeof(vertices), vertices, 0);

glCreateVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glEnableVertexArrayAttrib(vao, 0);
glVertexArrayAttribFormat(vao, 0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0);

glVertexArrayVertexBuffer(vao, 0, buffer, 0, sizeof(GLfloat) * 3);
glVertexArrayAttribBinding(vao, 0, 0);
```

Comment: Great to see you active on this new Stack Exchange site dedicated to graphics.